# How can I wait for text file to be written, read changes line by line and print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, semaphore, file-handling

I have a code which will open a .text file in append mode, generate a random string and append those string in the file in a time gap.

## Program: Random_Generation

```
import os
import sys
import string
import random
import time

class RandomCreation():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def string_generator(self, size):
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
    try:
        while True:
            random_cration = RandomCreation(path)
            data = random_cration.string_generator(10)
            f = open(f'{path}/try_file.txt', 'a+')
            f.write(data +"\n")
            print('Successfully Appended')
            time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        f.close()
        print('Exiting......')
        exit()
```

This program running perfectly.

I want to write another program(called File_Handling) which will open the same .text file and will read the file line by line. This program is dependent on the above-mentationed Program Named Random_Generation. This File_Handling program will wait until the text file generated. After the generation of the text file, it will read the file line by line and print the content, while it's still being written by the Random_Generation program. If there is no new line to be read, then it will wait for a new line, but it does not stop itself. So, when new lines are available then, I would like to print the new lines only.

## Program: File_Handling

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import time

path = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
filename = f'{path}/try_file.txt'
while not os.path.exists(filename):
    time.sleep(1)
if os.path.exists(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        print(f'{num}: {line}')
    file.close()
```

Both codes are running parallel. The condition of the program File_Handling:

- If the text file is empty then it will wait for the availability of a new line
- If there exist some lines in the text file then, it will read those lines, line by line until the end of the file.
- After reaching at the end of the file, it will wait for the availability of a new line.
- It never goes back to those lines which were read before.
- Writing and reading program both are not synchronized.
- There can be written at any time of point.
- The only fact that after write read will occur until the end of the file.

To reach the goal, it necessarily wants semaphore and maybe async. But should I incorporate them?

I can not able to do as required in File_Handling program, Please Help!!!

Comment: What you're asking for is an extremely broad topic that comes under [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). You essentially want some way of blocking the file from being read when it's being appended to. There are underlying questions of whether all the lines need to be read and whether both processes should run in sync. All that aside, you could try renaming the file right before appending to and renaming it back after the append operation. You could also set aside another file that contains a flag which signals whether the write operation is complete or not.

Comment: Or you could check for line numbers and the newline character to ensure a full line is being read. However, ensure that what you're doing is really necessary. This question seems like you may be complicating things unnecessarily and ending up in an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: You should consider using of named pipes instead of files